# Differentiate between x:Name and Name in Wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, tags

i'm beginner in Wpf programmation, i need to know the difference between `Name` and `x:Name`

```
<label Name="lab" ></label>
```

and

```
<label x:Name="lab" ></label>
```

what is the differences between the two lines above?. In code behind, How can i differentiate between `Name` and `x:Name` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088322/wpf-what-is-difference-between-name-and-xname):

They refer to the same thing, but you have to use the x: prefix when defining a `UserControl`.

[In WPF, what are the differences between the x:Name and Name attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes)

[Is there any difference in x:name and name for controls in xaml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379230/is-there-any-difference-in-xname-and-name-for-controls-in-xaml-file)

This from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> any WPF application scenarios can avoid any use of the x:Name
>   attribute, because the Name dependency property as specified in the
>   default XAML namespace for several of the important base classes such
>   as FrameworkElement and FrameworkContentElement satisfies this same
>   purpose. There are still some common XAML and WPF scenarios where code
>   access to an element with no Name property at the framework level is
>   important. For example, certain animation and storyboard support
>   classes do not support a Name property, but they often need to be
>   referenced in code in order to control the animation. You should
>   specify x:Name as an attribute on timelines and transforms that are
>   created in XAML, if you intend to reference them from code later. If
>   Name is available as a property on the class, Name and x:Name can be
>   used interchangeably as attributes, but a parse exception will result
>   if both are specified on the same element. If the XAML is markup
>   compiled, the exception will occur on the markup compile, otherwise it
>   occurs on load. Name can be set using XAML attribute syntax, and in
>   code using SetValue; note however that setting the Name property in
>   code does not create the representative field reference within the
>   XAML namescope in most circumstances where the XAML is already loaded.
>   Instead of attempting to set Name in code, use NameScope methods from
>   code, against the appropriate namescope. Name can also be set using
>   property element syntax with inner text, but that is uncommon. In
>   contrast, x:Name cannot be set in XAML property element syntax, or in
>   code using SetValue; it can only be set using attribute syntax on
>   objects because it is a directive.