# Showing the mouse position on a popup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In the XAML I created a popup:

```
<Popup Name="PopupWindow" Placement="Mouse" IsOpen="False" StaysOpen="False" Opened="PopupWindow_Opened">
    <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="AntiqueWhite">
        <Label Name="myLabel" Content="Hello World!" />
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

In the code behind, in the `OnMouseClick()` event handler:

```
var position = e.GetPosition(mainPanel);
PopupWindow.IsOpen = true;
```

However I do not know how to get a reference to `myLabel` in order to update the value, since it is created inside the XAML directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `x:Name` instead of `Name` and then refer your object like so

XAML

```
<Popup Name="PopupWindow" Placement="Mouse" IsOpen="False" StaysOpen="False" Opened="PopupWindow_Opened">
    <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="AntiqueWhite">
        <Label x:Name="myLabel" Content="Hello World!" />
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

C#

```
var position = e.GetPosition(mainPanel);
this.myLabel.Content = position.ToString();
```

`x:Name` is a xaml concept, used mainly to reference elements. When you give an element the `x:Name` xaml attribute, "the specified x:Name becomes the name of a field that is created in the underlying code when xaml is processed, and that field holds a reference to the object." (MSDN) So, it's a designer-generated field, which has internal access by default.

`Name` is the existing string property of a FrameworkElement, listed as any other wpf element property in the form of a xaml attribute.

More about the subject:

[Differentiate between x:Name and Name in Wpf application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798175/differentiate-between-xname-and-name-in-wpf-application)

Answer (score 1):

You could do some casting:

```
Border border = PopupWindow.Child as Border;
Label label = border.Child as Label;
label.Content = "...";
```