# Using x:Name or Name in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

My understanding of x:Name vs Name is that some controls have a Name property, that is basically the same as setting x:Name.

Is there an advantage to using Name when it is available over x:Name?

Here's my [reference](http://www.wpfwiki.com/Default.aspx?Page=WPF%20Q16.4&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) for understanding x:Name vs Name.

Comment: Sorry ... I did search for this question as I was sure it must have been asked already, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If Name is available as a property on the class, Name and x:Name can be used interchangeably as attributes, but an error will result if both are specified on the same element.

Source: [x:Name Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx)

In other words, it makes no difference which one you use; just don't use both on the same element.

Comment: Sometimes it makes a difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380112/why-cant-i-use-the-name-attribute-on-usercontrol-in-the-same-assembly

Answer (score 12):

For any that has stumbled upon this question ... here's is a [very detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes/593151#593151).  Thanks to Taylor L for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7):

You're safer using x:Name because it works all the time, where as Name depends on the particular control implementation.