# How to access control in Code Behind that was 'created' in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a control I 'created' in XAML that I want to access through the Code Behind.

```
<wincontrols:LiveTileFrameElement Name="PendingAuthsFrame1" Text="Pending" />

this.PendingAuthsFrame1.Text = "334";
```

However, I get a Build Error on the second statement above stating `MyApp.MainWindow does not contain a definition for 'PendingAuthsFrame1' and no extension method....`
it keeps going but you get the idea I'm guessing.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have Telerik.WinControls.UI in project references? LiveTileFrameElement is teleric control for winforms, i am right?

Comment: Yup, I do.  Thanks.  You just made me remember I should probably spell out that this control is hosted inside a WinFormsControlHost in XAML.  Not sure if that makes a difference but I can get at 'normal' WPF controls in my Code Behind so I'm guessing, yes.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `x:Name` instead of `Name`. That should do the trick.

Comment: That worked!  Any chance you could, succinctly, state why?  Should I ALWAYS use x:Name vs Name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/593151/351383 http://stackoverflow.com/a/1929978/351383

Comment: In a few words: `x:Name` is a XAML language feature and maps during code generation to fields in code behind. That's what gets generated in *.cs.g file during build. 

`Name` on the other hand is a property defined on FrameworkElement and can be handled by the control as the author pleases — it's not always mapped to the XAML `x:Name`. Some elements don't have a `Name` property. 

Hence, you should always use `x:Name` to name your elements for reference in XAML and code behind :)