# Code-behind can't find control declared in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind, xname

After googling for sometime, `x:Name` should be a solution to my problem.

In my wtfapp.xaml there is a `TextBlock` that will be created during runtime:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="wtf" Text="{Binding fTx}"/>
```

In the code-behind, it should be accessible so I tried to change its Foreground color:

```
wtf.Foreground = Brushes.DarkGreen;
```

When I compile, an error shows up:

> The name "wtf" does not exist in the current context.

If I'm not mistaken, that means `TextBlock` "wtf" is not accessible.

How can I resolve the reference?

EDIT:

XAML:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate_NextAnime_HOVER">
        <Grid Margin="2,0,1,0" Width="82" Height="120" >
            <Image x:Name="NxtAnime_Image" Width="82" Height="120" Stretch="UniformToFill" Panel.ZIndex="0">
                <Image.Source>
                    <BitmapImage UriCachePolicy="Revalidate" UriSource="{Binding rLocalPic}"/>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
            <Grid Panel.ZIndex="1" >
                <Border Background="#7F000000" Panel.ZIndex="0" x:Name="brd">
                    <Popup IsOpen="True" StaysOpen="True" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=brd}" Placement="Top">
                        <StackPanel Background="#FFC54B4B" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="334" Width="430">
                            <Image Width="213" Height="326" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="4,4,4,6" Source="{Binding LocalPic}"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="4,4,4,4" Name="are">
                                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,10" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="22" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="200" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Relation: " FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="wtf" Text="{Binding Type}" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Popup>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This is a `DataTemplate` for `ListBoxItem`.

Comment: You need `Name`, not `x:Name`.

Comment: @SLaks it doesn't work :( you may want to see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569782/how-to-access-control-in-code-behind-that-was-created-in-xaml

Comment: That's because in that example it's a user-defined control. In your case you want Name, not x:Name.

Comment: can you provide the xaml code where your textblock is defined, so we can see the context?

Comment: is that enough? pasting the whole xaml would be a problem but i will do if it neccesary

Comment: You're inside a Popup so at the page level those fields won't be in scope.

Comment: @Jeff Oh i see, then is there any alternative? Or is there a way so it would be accessible? Sorry, im very new to wpf :D

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. How are you using the popup?

Comment: I copied that XAML into a UserControl and managed to get the `wft` element just fine.

Comment: Is this in a template at all?

Comment: @CameronMacFarland Ah, you're right. Sorry for the red herring. In that case if it's not in a template I have no idea. Possibly a build issue.

Comment: To get a `TextBlock` inside an template and change it's properties in code you should use `FrameworkTemplate.FindName` Method. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117944/listbox-items-return-string-when-datatemplate-is-button

Comment: @CameronMacFarland yes its a DataTemplate for ListBoxItem

Comment: @Jeff I've updated the xaml

Comment: Yes, as @user2946329 pointed out you'll need to find the control since it's part of a template. My original assertion was incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to get an element from a template, as a template is like a factory, and will generate multiple instances.

As suggested by user2946329 in the comments, [ListBox items return string, when DataTemplate is Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117944/listbox-items-return-string-when-datatemplate-is-button) answers how to get the element, but there might be another way to do what you want.

For example, if you want to change the color of the `wtf` element you can do so with a trigger.

`<DataTemplate.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ...}" Value="False">
       <Setter TargetName="wtf" Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"/>
   </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>`

Comment: Nice, i will use this then :)