# Access user control name in MainWindow from within user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I can't seem to be able to access the `x:Name` property that I set on a user control in my `MainWindow.xaml`, from within that user control.

The `this.Name` property is empty! Probably, this isn't the property I'm looking for ([Why can't I use the Name attribute on UserControl in the same assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380112/why-cant-i-use-the-name-attribute-on-usercontrol-in-the-same-assembly)).

I tried placing a debug stop on a dummy line right after the standard `InitializeComponent();` in the `UserControl1()` constructor, and dig through the properties in the various base classes, but haven't found anything that resemebles `x:Name`.

My MainWindow.xaml looks like this:

```csharp
  <Window x:Class="UserControlName.MainWindow"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:xw="clr-namespace:UserControlName"

          Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
      <Grid>
          <xw:UserControl1 x:Name="sup" />
      </Grid>
  </Window>
```

And this is my UserControl1.xaml:

```xaml
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlName.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="sup" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the code inside UserControl1.cs:

```
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.sup.Content = "label: " + this.Name;
    }
```

The label should be set to "label: sup", but this.name is empty, so it's just label.

Comment: Show some code as well.

Comment: _"I can seem"_ - do you mean _"I **can't** seem"_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x:Name attribute is applied after the constructor has been called, if you add a button to the user control

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label x:Name="sup" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <Button Height="25" Width="100" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

And

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.sup.Content = "label: " + this.Name;
}
```

This should update the label with the name provided in the mainwindow.

To get this updated without a interaction, add this to the usercontrol definition

```
Loaded="UserControl1_OnLoaded"
```

And in codebehind

```
private void UserControl1_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.sup.Content = "label: " + this.Name;
}
```

Comment: How can I offload the accessing of x:name until it is set? I can't use a button or something.

Comment: It seems I have to do UserControl1_OnLoaded in the MainWindow code. Is there a way to do this inside the usercontrol's code?

Comment: You can add those in the usercontrol xaml, and I kinda assumed you would do so.