# I've recently started learning WPF on my own. What is difference when declaring Name vs. x:Name?

Tags: c#, wpf

For instance, I have this code:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Name="TheRectangle" Fill="AliceBlue" Height="100" Width="100">            
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

**VS.**

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle x:Name="TheRectangle" Fill="AliceBlue" Height="100" Width="100">            
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Thank you very much for the information. I'm very excited about learning something new like this. :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[wpfwiki](http://www.wpfwiki.com/Default.aspx?Page=WPF%20Q16.4&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

> There is basically no difference
>   between the two.
>
> The "x:Name" expression is used in
>   XAML to assign a name to an object
>   that will be used to access the object
>   from the code-behind.
>
> Many classes of the framework expose a
>   Name property, which does exactly
>   this. For these classes, both x:Name
>   and the Name property can be used
>   interchangeably.

Comment: One minor difference: Name cannot (for some crazy reason) be used in XAML on a control that is declared in the same assembly as the XAML file.  In that scenario, you *must* use x:Name instead.

Comment: So it's better for me to be safe and make it a habbit of always using x:Name in the case a framework class doesn't haev a Name property? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes)

Basically, x:Name is used by WPF to be accessed in Runtime and by XAML to generate fields in the code behind.