# ReSharper: 'Name' attribute is not allowed here; use 'x:Name' instead in XAML

Tags: xaml, resharper

ReSharper's complaining about some of my XAML with the following error:

> 'Name' attribute is not allowed here
>   because type 'FlashingTextBlock' is
>   implemented in the same project. Use
>   'x:Name' instead

What's the problem here? Should I do what it says?

Answer (score 3):

See an excellent explanations in this answer, and decide for your own ;)

[In WPF, what are the differences between the x:Name and Name attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes)

Comment: Cool. So why is it a problem that it's implemented in the same project?

Comment: It isnt a problem.. simply put, x:Name makes your control available in the code behind as well.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: why does *ReSharper* think it's a problem that it's implemented in the same project?

Answer (score 0):

Does FlashingTextBlock have a System.Windows.Markup.RuntimeNameProperty attribute?

According to "Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed" by Adam Nathan:

> ... you can simply set its Name property to a string rather than use the x:Name syntax. You can use either mechanism, but you can't use both simultaneously.

Comment: No, it doesn't have a `RuntimeNameProperty` attribute. It's a `UserControl`; presumably it inherits `Name` from `FrameworkElement`?

Comment: Yes - I found a reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.runtimenamepropertyattribute%28VS.85%29.aspx