# Is there any difference in x:name and name for controls in xaml file?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-2.0

I am new in Silverlight.
When I add some control to my xaml file with Visual Studio it set controls name with Name property, but there is also x:Name.
Is there any difference and when to use each of them?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In WPF, what are the differences between the x:Name and Name attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes)

Comment: Very close but this one was for Silverlight, not sure it is important after 4 years :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**In Brief**

Yes there is a difference.  The bottom line is that `x:Name` can be used on object elements that do not have `Name` properties of their own.

**A longer explanation**

You can only use `Name` on an element that represents an object that actually does have a `Name` property.  For example anything that derives from `FrameworkElement`.

The `x:Name` attribute may be placed on any element that represents an object **regardless** of whether that object actually has a `Name` property.  If the object does have a `Name` property then the value of `x:Name` will be assigned to it hence you can't have both `x:Name` and `Name` on the same element.

When an object has a `Name` property or an `x:Name` property the value of that property is associated with the objects entry in the object tree.  It is via the object tree that the `FindName` method of a `FrameworkElement` can find an object.  `FindName` can find objects by name even if that object does not carry a `Name` property of its own since it uses the name recorded in the object tree.

The autogenerated code for a `UserControl` will contain field definitions for any element that that has a `Name` or `x:Name` property.  The  `InitialiseComponent` method that is generated will use the `FindName` method to assign values to these fields.

**Example**

The above Xaml creates two fields `LayoutRoot` of type `Grid` and `MyBrush` of type `SolidColorBrush`.  If you were to change `x:Name="LayoutRoot"` to `Name="LayoutRoot"` that would change nothing.  `Grid` has a `Name` property.  However try changing `x:Name="MyBrush"` to `Name="MyBrush"`.  That doesn't work because `SolidColorBrush` doesn't have a name property.  With the above Xaml you can then do code like this:-

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyBrush.Color = Colors.LightGray;
    }
```

Open the definition of `InitializeComponent` and take a look at the auto generated code.

Comment: So, we'd rather use `x:Name` than `Name` to make sure the naming works all the time & free us from wondering whether the control supports Name property or not. Am I right?

Comment: @Nam:  Yes I tend to do that, it also helps things look consistent.

Answer (score 2):

No, you just can't use them both. x:Name is what the XAML preprocessor actually uses and Name is just a convience property provided on the FrameworkElement class to set it.

From the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189028(VS.95).aspx):

*If Name is available as a property on an element, Name and x:Name can be used interchangeably, but an error results if both attributes are specified on the same element.*

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: if you're writing stuff out in XAML, it's probably best to just use x:Name consistently.

Long answer: A previous answer mentioned that Name is a "convienience" property for accessing x:Name. That's correct. However, now that the tools environment for XAML in both Visual Studio and the Expression series has really matured and you are seeing more and more tool-generated XAML, you are also probably seeing more and more x:Name as opposed to Name. The tools prefer x:Name because that way they don't take a somewhat risky dependency (potentially specific to framework) re: how x:Name and Name are really the same, and they don't need to flipflop between setting Name if something happens to be a FrameworkElement and then x:Name on something like a Storyboard and generating a duality if you were to look at this XAML through something like a DOM. In other words, the "Name" attribute in XAML really is a lot less "convenient" to use nowadays than might have been conceived of in the original API design. Part of the "convenience" was to not have to map x:, but you have to do that anyways for x:Class and by now pretty much everyone has gotten used to using x: attributes and the general principles of XAML markup effectively.

I'm not sure of the statement made by the original poster that VS encourages using Name. Yes, Name appears as an intellisense option, but so does x:Name. And all the cases I see in the templates where an object is given a starting name are using x:Name even tho most of these are FrameworkElements.