# x: in front of the button in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

What is the difference between these 2 lines? Visually I haven't noticed anything different. Sorry I am just getting started with Silverlight.

```
<Button Content="Click me" Name="myButton" FontSize="18" Width="150" Height="45" />
```

and

```
<Button Content="Click me" x:Name="myButton" FontSize="18" Width="150" Height="45" />
```

Comment: See my answer here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379230/is-there-any-difference-in-xname-and-name-for-controls-in-xaml-file/3383442#3383442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nothing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189028%28VS.95%29.aspx) (see the remarks in particular).