# What's the difference between Name and x:Name?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

In Silverlight XAML, I can give a control a name like this:

```
<Button Name="MyButton" />
```

or like this:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" />
```

So, what's the difference?

Comment: same question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes

Comment: @Toolsche: Its not quite the same, that question is in the WPF context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [Is there any difference in x:name and name for controls in xaml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379230/is-there-any-difference-in-xname-and-name-for-controls-in-xaml-file) post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes/593151#593151), as posted in response to the same question (asked in relation to WPF).

Comment: That answer you point is useful but refers to WPF.  In Silveright there is no `RuntimeNamePropertyAttribute`, `x:Name` is only mapped to `Name` if present in Silverlight.