# cannot find Name of DataGridColumn programmatically

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, datagridcolumn

I found the Columns collection in my datagrid, and was hoping to iterate through it to find a certain column Name. However, I can't figure out how to address the x:Name attribute of the column. This xaml illustrates my problem with a DataGridTextColumn and a DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
<t:DataGrid x:Name="dgEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" Height="300" >
    <t:DataGrid.Columns>
        <t:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FirstName" Header="FirstName"
Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <t:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="LastName" Header="LastName" >
            <t:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </t:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </t:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </t:DataGrid.Columns>
</t:DataGrid>
```

And here is my code:

```
    DataGrid dg = this.dgEmployees;
    foreach (var column in dg.Columns) 
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("name: " + (string)column.GetValue(NameProperty));
    }
```

At runtime, no value is present; column.GetValue doesn't return anything. Using Snoop, I confirmed that there is no Name property on either DataGridTextColumn or DataGridTemplateColumn.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

WPF has two different, yet similar concepts, x:Name, which is used to create a field which references an element defined in XAML, i.e. connecting your code-behind to your XAML, and FrameworkElement.Name, which uniquely names an element within a namescope.

If an element has a FrameworkElement.Name property, x:Name will set this property to the value given in XAML. However, there are instances where it is useful to link non FrameworkElement elements to fields in code-behind, such as in your example.

See this related question:

[In WPF, what are the differences between the x:Name and Name attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes)

As an alternative, you could define your own attached property which can be used to name the columns. The attached property is defined as follows:

```
public class DataGridUtil
{

    public static string GetName(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(NameProperty);
    }

    public static void SetName(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(NameProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Name", typeof(string), typeof(DataGridUtil), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

}
```

You can then assign a name to each column ...

```
xmlns:util="clr-namespace:WPFDataGridExamples"

<t:DataGrid x:Name="dgEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" Height="300" >
    <t:DataGrid.Columns>
        <t:DataGridTextColumn util:DataGridUtil.Name="FirstName" Header="FirstName"
Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <t:DataGridTemplateColumn util:DataGridUtil.Name="LastName" Header="LastName" >
            <t:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </t:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </t:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </t:DataGrid.Columns>
</t:DataGrid>
```

Then access this name in code as follows:

```
DataGrid dg = this.dgEmployees;
foreach (var column in dg.Columns) 
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("name: " + DataGridUtil.GetName(column));
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Your message and link are informative. But I'm not sure how they answer my question. Are you saying that this code will not work since DataGridColumn is not a FrameworkElement? Can you suggest an alternate approach?

Comment: Daniel, how about an attached property? See my edited answer above.

Comment: Colin, that worked for me. Thank you. I wonder why they didn't make a 'Name' DP for DataGridColumns.

Comment: thnaks for your great answer,how can i use this property in codebehind?for example i want to set name property for this columns: `columnCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataGridTextColumn>();
            columnCollection.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "ColumnHeader", Binding = new Binding("ColumnName)" , ??Name=????});
           `

Comment: Sigh.  -(Infinity) to Tinyflacid, I mean Microsoft, for not including a "Name" `DependencyProperty` in the `DataGridColumn` Class.  I know much of the complexity (vs. WinForms) is (supposedly) needed for more flexibility, but I doubt they can claim that *excuse* in this case.  And even *with* a "Name" DP, the Code Behind still needs to dupe the Magic String from XAML (ala when MS thought Magic Strings were ok in RaisePropertyChanged Call.  SMH).  WinForms created separate `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` Objects in the *.Designer.cs with Names that could be Intellisensed / compile-time checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq query to find name of the datagrid column Headers

```
dgvReports.Columns.Select(a=>a.Header.ToString()).ToList()
```

where dgvReports is name of the datagrid.