# AutomationProperties.Name VS x:Name

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, accessibility, ui-automation

There is no difference for the "CodedUI test builder" between the `AutomationProperties.Name` and `x:Name`. But the first one can override the second one.
Also the AtomationProperties.Name supports data binding, `x:Name` of course doesn't.

[As we know](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/07/02/silverlight-wpf-dont-name-elements-unless-you-have-to-why-xnaming-everything-is-bad) if you are using the MVVM pattern it is best to only use `x:Name` when needed.

So should `AutomationProperties.Name` be preferred to `x:Name`?

Comment: I've read it and correct me if I'm wrong, but the article is not saying anywhere that you should use one over the other it's just an article about: "Should I give everything a name?"

Comment: @Silvermind I have updated the text to more clearly indicate the content of the article.

Comment: @Trisped It does not change the fact that I am stating. The link is not related to the question, it is not about preference for name over x:name or vice versa.

Answer (score 26):

### Summary

`x:Name` and `AutomationProperties.Name` are two totally different things, so the question "should I use one or the other" is based on a false premise: in general, you *cannot* use one or the other.

The purpose of `x:Name` is to identify a WPF control in code-behind so that the developer can access it. It is not meaningful (or unique) outside the scope of the class that models a specific WPF element.

On the other hand, the purpose of `AutomationProperties.Name` is to identify a user interface element in the context of a dialog or other type of window that is presented to the user for interaction. Specifically, its value should match what a user would perceive as the "label" of that user interface element (so that e.g. an accessibility tool can inform the user of the purpose of the element).

While any tool (such as a XAML compiler) can choose to use the value of `x:Name` for `AutomationProperties.Name` as well doesn't mean that it's something you should do; IMHO this is exactly the type of "convenience" that results in problems because the difference between the two is hidden from the developer, so invariably one or the other property would end up having a semantically wrong value.

Information on the semantic and technical aspects of each of the property follows in the next sections.

### x:Name

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx) page explains that

> After x:Name is applied to a framework's backing programming model,
>   the name is equivalent to the variable that holds an object reference
>   or an instance as returned by a constructor.
>
> The value of an x:Name directive usage must be unique within a XAML
>   namescope.
>
> [...]
>
> Under the standard build configuration for a WPF application that uses
>   XAML, partial classes, and code-behind, the specified x:Name becomes
>   the name of a field that is created in the underlying code when XAML
>   is processed by a markup compilation build task, and that field holds
>   a reference to the object.

From the above we can tell that `x:Name`:

1. is used to access the element in code (not XAML), since it controls the name of the field that holds the element
2. must be unique within a [XAML namescope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx) (since you cannot have two fields with the same name in code)

### AutomationProperties.Name

The [WPF accessibility documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg712258.aspx) explains that

> The Name for an automation element is assigned by the developer. The
>   Name property should always be consistent with the label text on
>   screen. For example, the Name must be “Browse…” for the button element
>   with “Browse…” as the label.

Comment: so I guess you are supposed to also localize AutomationProperties.Name