# Why AutomationProperties are needed in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, ui-automation

As per my understanding, AutomationProperties can be utilized to identify names of controls by UI Automation clients.

I want to understand need to create separate set of automation properties, and not using x:Name for the same purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AutomationProperties.Name VS x:Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605777/automationproperties-name-vs-xname)

Comment: It is not duplicate.  Question in the link( AutomationProperties.Name VS x:Name)  specifies what is the difference. My question is why?

Comment: Why? Because there is a difference in what each of them should be used for. The same reason that people use both cars and trucks for transportation instead of only one type of vehicle. Do you feel that my answer there leaves open questions? I would be happy to improve it.

Comment: See, we have x:Name property to identify any element in the code behind, or at run time. 
Now why the same cannot be used in place of AutomationProperties.Name. Anywhere, if i need to know the identifier for an element, i can use x:Name.

Well if there is a reasoning that x:Name is not suitable for so and so reasons, and therefore, there was need to introduce AutomationProperties, it is fine, i just need to understand the so and so reasons.

But so far i am unable to understand.

Comment: Because `x:Name` identifies the control to the programmer, while `AutomationProperties.Name` to the user. A good name for one of them is a very bad name for the other.

Comment: AutomationProperties.Name should be human-readable text, "File name", for example, rather than "filename1", and should also be localized as appropriate. This makes it useful for an end-user (eg. when read out by a Screen Reader to a blind user, or used as a match string in speech commanding) but not appropriate for use in code. Conversely, Name is for developers, and shouldn't be exposed to end-users, since it's an internal implementation detail.

Comment: @Jon that link answers the question +1

Answer (score 12):

Let’s think about a text box, in your application it is the PhoneNumberTextBox, and you also have a PhoneNumberLabel, and PhoneNumberValidationTick.   These are then displayed inside of a group box with a label showing “Customer”

A blind person trying to use your application would like the screen reader to say “Customer Phone Number” when they tab into the text box, likewise a tester writing an automated UI test for your application would like to be able to find the text box that contains the “Customer Phone Number”.

Now what if your application has been translated to German…. Would the blind user not want the screen reader to say ”Kundentelefonnummer“?

Now imagine you change your app to use a PhoneNumberInputControl, you will likely want to change the names of the control in your code, but the tester would rather wish that the control name does not change….

So we need the concept of a name that is used by programs that try to walk the “important” logical controls of an application at run time and automate something about how a user interacts with the application.

Answer (score 4):

I consider my answer came a little bit late, but I found a proper explanation and I would like to share it with all programmers to improve their work in this field of automation.

Nowadays, I'm mostly working with some automation tools called RPAs, specifically [UiPath](https://www.uipath.com) and [Automation Anywhere](https://www.automationanywhere.com).

For many months I have been struggling with some tools to be automated because they were developed in [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) and not [Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), which makes them very hard to automate and we have depended a lot on image recognitions not because they were poorly designed or didn't work as expected, but because the `AutomationProperties` were never considered in any project.

In order to find the answer to why the controls were not recognized by any RPA and we were forced to use ***Image Recognition*** all the time, especially in tools like UiPath that is being built in ***VB.NET***, which should have full connection with Windows, it was incredible to believe that it couldn't work well and it pushed me to investigate deeper about the root cause and I created the following test case.

A basic WPF application without any automation properties (as default) that contains just a `Grid`, a `Label`, a `Button`, and a `TextBox`:

```
<Window x:Class="UiPathExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UiPathExample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="82,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="300,135,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, if you try to search for any control with [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2017), [Ui Explorer](https://studio.uipath.com/docs/uipath-explorer) from UiPath, Object Cloning from Automation Anywhere, etc. This is your result:

[image: example 1]

All controls are undiscoverable by any RPA or tool. For this example, I'm using the Ui Explorer of UiPath (I could have used Spy++ too and I would have gotten the same result); however, if you modify the code a little bit and add all Automation IDs as suggested in this site:

http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/11/03/coded-ui-tests-automationid-or-how-to-find-the-chose-one-control/

The new code will look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="UiPathExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UiPathExample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Window1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Grid1">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,60,0,0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="btnButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="lbl1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="82,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="300,135,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="txtAutomationEx"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And now all controls become accessible to the Ui Explorer like the button that I highlighted:

[image: example 2]

Based on my personal experience this is why I consider we should use them; especially, in these times when RPAs are becoming iconic in any industry. Also, you are going to **save a considerable amount of time** for you or your team if anyone will automate the tools you are building in the future because without those properties the automation would be highly inefficient since you will rely on **image recognitions** all the time as it was in my case.

Furthermore, here you can read more about the Automation Properties:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-properties-overview

Happy Automation!

**P.S.:**

> An interesting fact in my investigation is that any **Windows Forms**
> project has its controls already exposed since the beginning to any
> automation tool without additional effort and that's why they are
> faster to automate.

Comment: A typical WinForm control is a... window! Or even several windows at a time. So, each and every screen is a hyerarchy and tools like Spy++ just enumerate them. Nothing fancy, until... Until you face so called "windowless" controls. Unlike the legacy, they don't have a window underneath, they rent it from a host instead. And WPF/UWP is all about windowless: a great way to obtain amazing transformations, shapes, transitions etc. However, you see the price: without Automation Properties, there is no way to discover the real hyerarchy because there is just one main window with a custom renderer.

Comment: Thanks, @YurySchkatula?