# a basic question about WPF

Tags: wpf

I am learning WPF and found that the way it work is completely different. I have two questions about the following XAML markup:

```
<Button x:name="test" BackGround="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
```

1) Why x:name? Since name is a property, then why x should be prefix it. Is there any special meaning for x:name?

2) What is StaticResource and where is StaticResource stored?

Please explain in detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x is a prefix for an XML namespace. Here is the official doc on this: [XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping for WPF XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx)

If you want more  on the XML namespace topic (unrelated to XAML): http://wap.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

StaticResource is a "Markup extension", here is the official doc again: [StaticResource Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

About x:Name you should read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes).

Xaml parser transformed directive :

```
{StaticResource MyColor}
```

into C# code like this:

```
Resource["MyColor"]
```

> Static resource lookup behavior
>
> 1. The lookup process checks for the requested key within the resource
>      dictionary defined by the element that
>      sets the property.
> 2. The lookup process then traverses the logical tree upward, to the parent
>      element and its resource dictionary.
>      This continues until the root element
>      is reached.
> 3. Next, application resources are checked. Application resources are
>      those resources within the resource
>      dictionary that is defined by the
>      Application object for your WPF
>      application.
>
> [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx)

Simply if you define something in App.xaml, parent or current control Resources you can use StaticResource to lookup those to get the value under the key.