# How to access to control references in WPF Xaml?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have some controls where I set their `Name` property to unique names, but I am unable to access them in the matching C# code file.

I have tried:

```
this.ControlName
MainWindow.ControlName
ControlName
```

but it does "see" them.

How do I do this?

Also do I have to do something special for nested controls inside wrap panels, grid views, etc?

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Reflection;

namespace EditorWindow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow ( )
        {

        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="EditorWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Effects Editor">

    <DockPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="EffectsListView">
        </ListView>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you post sample of your xaml and codebehind files?

Comment: @Lav: Ok posted the code. Thanks again.

Comment: please dont delete the InitializeComponent method in the constructor.

Comment: Sorry I deleted it while posting, in the actual code it exists.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For accessing any element in code behind you will need to set x:Name directive. 
It tells the XAML parser to add a field representing the named element to the automatically generated portion of the Window class just like Winforms.

In a WPF application, there’s no requirement to name each and every element. You should name only those elements which you want to programatically interact with.

An example:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tblText" Text="Stackoverflow rocks."></TextBlock>
```

**EDIT:**
I used the following code and I was able to access the list view:

```
namespace WpfApplicationUnleashed
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {    
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            EffectsListView.Width = 10;
        }    
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationUnleashed.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationUnleashed"
        Title="Window1" >
    <DockPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="EffectsListView"></ListView>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: So this name has to be unique across all controls? I can access any control with its name no matter how nested it is?

Comment: Still doesn't work for some reason. I didn't change the definition of x btw.

Comment: No, It doesn't work for me. I have tried x:Name, but it doesn't work.

Comment: MIght be good to note that by default, simply setting x:Name won't make that control accessible EVERYWHERE in your project, just within the code-behind specifically for the xml where the x:Name is defined.

Comment: To make it visible in whole namespace, use a cast to your special Window1: `var mw = (Window1)Application.Current.MainWindow;`, then you can call: `mw.EffectsListView.Width = 10;`

Answer (score 5):

have you set their `x:Name="ControlName"` property in xaml?

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx) is more information on x:Name directive.

For example:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1">Click Me</Button>
```

Comment: I did, but didn't use x:Name. I just used Name="ControlName". Why do you use x? Also if it's necessary why did the xaml compiler didn't warn me? What would happen if you omit x?

Comment: Still doesn't work for some reason. I didn't change the definition of x btw.

Comment: @JoanVenge Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes question and you will get answer of the diff beween Name and x:Name