# Accessing members of Elysium WPF MainWindow.xaml from code

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF C# application, the UI has been designed in the appropriate .xaml file but I can't seem to access any of the members from a C# source file.

I can't post the source as I am working on a private project.

Just a bit of info, I am using the Elysium library to create a metro themed UI.

Just hoping someone has past experience as I am new to WPF.

http://elysium.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to an instance of the `MainWindow` class, then typically you should be able to access its members as fields or properties using that reference, as long as they have the appropriate access modifier.

That's really all that can be said without code.

Comment: I am so sorry for wasting your time.
I have just managed to find this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316062/how-to-access-to-control-references-in-wpf-xaml) and it has solved my issue.

I didn't have a class member in the definition for my window.
`<metro:Window x:Class="my_namespace.MainWindow"`

Comment: There is a bigger issue here, why would you want to access them at all?  Have a read up on MVVM ...