# Why does WPF have x:Name and Name XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In WPF, what are the differences between the x:Name and Name attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes)

Why does WPF have x:Name and Name XAML?  What's the deal with x:Name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Long story short: x:Name is an attached property and can thus be set on everything. Name is not an attached property and thus is only available on things that expose a Name property. WPF aliases Name to x:Name so you are safe to always use x:Name and this is what is recommended as you can use it everywhere.