# Accessing Controls inside the content controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, radio-button, stackpanel

i have a StackPanel, which contain radio button, i want to access the value of the radio button at runtime, how can i get the radio button value, i am total newbie in WPF, any helps?

```
<StackPanel Height="73" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="105,78,0,0" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" >
    <RadioButton Content="Button1" Height="16" Name="radioButton1" Margin="10" />
    <RadioButton Content="Button2" Height="16" Name="radioButton2" Margin="10" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: If you are a *"total newbie"* you should not be here, but [someplace with documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268.aspx).

Comment: Abbas, I can highly recommend Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed by Adam Nathan.  If you spent just 3-4 hours with that very simple, very well written book, you would be way past the need to ask questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `radioButton1.IsChecked` from the codebehind.

Comment: Changing `Name` to `x:Name` does just about nothing.

Comment: Oh right, I always thought you needed to do x:Name to access from codebehind.

Comment: You only need [`x:Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx) for non-`FrameworkElements` as they have no `Name` property.

Comment: Interesting. Every day's a school day. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes