# Accessing XAML object in codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, code-behind

I have the following XAML code:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Coordinates" Text="{Binding Coors}"/>
```

How can I access this object from the codebehind? I'm trying to replace the hardcoded coordinates in Locaton, with the content of "Text":

```
private void DestinationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Location loc= new Location (20.2127297,-87.4625591);
    myMap.Center = loc;
    myMap.ZoomLevel = 8;
}
```

Comment: Just use the variable "Coors". Since your text value is bound to that variable it will hold the same value as your control.

Comment: I agree with Lee. Just make sure you are using INotifyPropertyChanged on the TextBlock so the property is always up to date (from whatever is updating it).

Comment: What if I'm not using any binding? what if it's just Text="Some text" ??

Answer (score 3):

Because you've provided it with an x:Name, you should be abled to access it as "Coordinates".

```
    var text = Coordinates.Text;
    var parsedLocation = <parsing logic here - use a Regex>
    myMap.Center = parsedLocation;
```

Also interesting - look at the difference between Name and X:Name [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes).

But Lee is right in the comments above. You should use the "Coors" property to at the value since it's databound there already.

Comment: How would I use it in the context of my button? I want to use the content of Coordinates.text instead of "20.2127297,-87.4625591"

private void DestinationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Location loc= new Location (20.2127297,-87.4625591);
    myMap.Center = loc;
    myMap.ZoomLevel = 8;
}

Comment: Unfortunately, it says "Coordinates does not exist in the current context"... Do I need to add anything to "DestinationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)" ?

Comment: Nope. As long as "Coordinates" and the event handler are part of the same class you should be able to see it.