# 'WindowName' does not contain a definition for 'Item'

Tags: c#, wpf

In windows presentation foundation, I have a custom UIControl called EquipmentList. When I intialize it like this in wpf:

```
<EquipmentList:EquipmentListControl Name="equipmentList" Margin="0,0,2,2"  />
```

I then try to reference it like this:

```
InitializeComponent();
this.equipmentList.SetReferenceList(referenceDevices);
```

I get the error:

> Error  1   'Equipment' does not contain a definition for 'equipmentList' and no extension method 'equipmentList' accepting a first argument of type 'FluentGCS.Windows.Equipment' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Resharper doesn't show an error. What's the problem?

Comment: Windows foundation presentation, they are different tags, use `WPF` instead.

Comment: try using x:Name instead of Name in your Xaml

Comment: After adding the XAML, If having issues, I find its good to re-build the solution before referencing it from the code behind. It wouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: Mark hall, can't you post this as an answer so I can accept it? xD

Comment: Another solution (that I prefer) is to hold your custom user controls in a different assembly. That way you can use the Name property and it will be properly mapped to the x:Name and you can use its value in the code-behind. Of course this approach depends on how your solution is structured and it may not always be suitable. If you want your user control in the same assembly then you have to use x:Name as @Mark Hall said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added comment as answer per OP's request.

Try using [`x:Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx) instead of `Name` see accepted answer of this [`SO question`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/593151/479512)