# Windows Phone xaml element name

Tags: xaml, user-interface, element, windows-phone

In Windows Phone xaml page, some element has **x:Name**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="simple" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
```

While others have **Name**

```
<TextBlock Name="tbSource" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="129,178,0,0"  Text="Source" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="304" />
```

What is the difference ?

Comment: possible duplicate. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x:` part is a namespace alias. It tells the compiler where the property exists. In this case it's pointing to the default namespace for XAML.
The `Name` property is part of `System.Object` which is in that namespace.
When you include `x:Name` to identify a property called `Name` in XAML what you're explicitly saying is that you're referring to the `Name` property of the underlying `System.Object`.  As all objects inherit from this it's accessible to all classes.

**Why might any of this matter?**
If you overrode the Name property in a class then specifying the namespace will allow you to be explicit about which version of `Name` you're referring to.
Side note: you will save yourself a lot of pain by never overriding `Name`.

**Does it matter which you use?**
No. As long as `Name` is never overridden and you need to refer to the specific version of it.

It's probably in your interest to be consistent in whether you use it or not. Most people do (as does VS when it creates controls for you) so it's probably easiest to keep them there.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Lacey, but what do you mean by overriding the Name property?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think x:Name elements are accessible in code by their name. e.g. PageTitle.Text = "some text". And "Name" is just a regular property of an element. Please also see the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx) about x:Name directive.

Comment: Elements declared with x:Name and Name are both accessible in code. The article is very hard to understand @@

Comment: Do you see vars in code for the elements that are not marked with x:Name?