# How to use textbox control created in XAML and use it in C# code?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this code to show/hide Canvas with some text boxes, and when I press a button it submits data from TextBox1 to database. The problem is that I don't know how to access TextBox1 in C# code behind.

For example this is some of my XAML code:

```
<ContentControl  Background="{x:Null}" >
  <ContentControl.Template>
     <ControlTemplate>
      <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Height="500" Name="stack1" Width="280">
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas1"  Height="400" >
              <TextBox Height="23" Name="TextBox1"  Width="70" />

    <Button Content="Submit" Name="submit_button" Click="submit_button_Click" />
        </Canvas>

  <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleshowhide" Content="Show/Hide" IsChecked="True" Height="50" />
      </StackPanel>
     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger SourceName="toggleshowhide" Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="canvas1" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
          </Trigger>
      <Trigger SourceName="toggleshowhide" Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="canvas1" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
          </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
  </ContentControl.Template>
     <Button Content="Button" Height="23" Name="submit" Width="74" />
</ContentControl>
```

And this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
private void submit_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Table VALUES (this.TextBox1.Text), con); 

      cmd.Connection = con;

         int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (temp > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OK", "Info !");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Some text !", "Error");
        }
```

If anyone can help I`ll really appreciate it. :)

Comment: We need to see your namespace declarations.

Comment: xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing elements generated from a ControlTemplate, you need to use the FindName method of the Template. In this case, give your ContnetControl a name:

```
<ContentControl  Background="{x:Null}" x:Name="MyContentControl">
```

And in the code behind, you can access the value of any of the generated elements by name using the FindName method:

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)MyContentControl.Template.FindName( "TextBox1", MyContentControl);
```

For more information, see: [How to: Find ControlTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
string v = this.TextBox1.Text;
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand('INSERT INTO Table VALUES (' + v + ');');
```

BTW this is pretty bad idea, read about sql injection...

Comment: I cannot use TextBox1.Text, it doesn`t recognize it, like its not there

Comment: Here is the picture of my app, hope it shows you what i want to achieve: http://fsrmo.comule.com/uploads/samplepicture.jpg

Comment: whole code or just this part,beause there is a lot of xaml code there :) ?

Comment: just the relevant part from the xaml and c#... just couple of lines of each

Comment: <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="85,105,0,0" x:Name="submit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" />

Comment: you changed the name of the button to "submit"

Comment: No, i gave you just example in code above, these button and textboxes names  are not actually in my code,they are just demo of what I want to achieve.

Comment: private void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {  
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Literatura VALUES ('" + this.dodaj.Text + "', '" + this.sampletextbox2.Text + "', '" + this.t3.Text + "','" + this.t4.Text + "','" + this.t5.Text + "','" + this.t6.Text + "','" + this.t7.Text + "','" + this.t8.Text + "')", con);
   cmd.Connection = con;
 int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (temp > 0)
       {
    MessageBox.Show("Some text");
            }
            else
            {
  MessageBox.Show("Some text!");
            }
        }

Comment: in this case this.dodaj.Text is mine TextBox1 :)

Comment: you read the values from dodaj, sampletextbox2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7 and t8 but not submit...

Comment: then change the name of the textbox in the xaml to be dodaj, not submit

Comment: It is already like that, I`m just giving you sample names to understand better because button names and textbox names are not in english. I should probably upload whole code somewhere in txt and send you link to better understand, if you are willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

give your TextBox an x:Name not a Name  ... does that even Compile ?

xaml :

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" />
```

cs :

```
var s = TextBox1.Text;
```

Comment: x:Name is essentially the same thing as Name in XAML. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/589874/9664