# WPF binding not work when create window using code

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Can anyone help me out why this code not work:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BuildMainWindow().Show();
    }

    private Window BuildMainWindow()
    {
        Window w = new Window();
        w.BeginInit();

        System.Windows.Controls.Grid g = new System.Windows.Controls.Grid();
        g.BeginInit();
        System.Windows.Controls.RowDefinition r1 = new System.Windows.Controls.RowDefinition();
        r1.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        System.Windows.Controls.RowDefinition r2 = new System.Windows.Controls.RowDefinition();
        r2.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        g.RowDefinitions.Add(r1);
        g.RowDefinitions.Add(r2);

        System.Windows.Controls.Button b1 = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
        b1.BeginInit();
        b1.Name = "b1";
        b1.Content = "Hello";
        Grid.SetRow(b1, 0);
        b1.EndInit();

        System.Windows.Controls.Button b2 = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
        b2.BeginInit();
        b2.Name = "b2";
        b2.Content = "World";
        Grid.SetRow(b2, 1);
        b2.EndInit();

        g.Children.Add(b1);
        g.Children.Add(b2);
        g.EndInit();

        w.Content = g;
        w.EndInit();

        System.Windows.Data.Binding bind = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Content");
        bind.ElementName = "b1";
        b2.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.ContentProperty, bind);

        return w;
    }
```

Here I tried to create a Window object and then add Grid and then add two buttons to grid, after this I try to bind b2.Content property with b1.Content, my expected result is after run, b2.Content will shown as "Hello", but after run, b2.Content is just empty, why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you can use `Binding.Source` on the actual b1 button instead of `Binding.ElementName` to its name:

```
//bind.ElementName = "b1";
bind.Source = b1;
```

Not sure why ElementName doesn't work though.. It may have something to do with the difference between `Name` and `x:Name` in XAML, which is where you'd normally use ElementName bindings.

[In WPF, what are the differences between the x:Name and Name attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes/593151#593151)

Comment: Thanks, this do works. The weird part is that if I create XAML (instead of create an Window instance by code) and put the binding code in an event handler, all works fine. This makes me think that maybe I forget something in the build window part.

Comment: Thanks, I finally fixed it by register each control name to window instance using FrameworkElement.RegisterName. Thanks for your help, the link about x:Name and Name really helped.

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware of the .RegisterName method :)