# Use object from MainForm in Class

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing a application in C# WPF.

I am having a small issue here.

In the class.cs, I have a line:

```
MessageBox.Show("Cancelled sending !");
```

And on my form I have a radioButton1.

How can I make it like

```
if (radioButton1.IsChecked == true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cancelled sending !");
}
```

Because when I try it, it doesn't find the radioButton1

I have tried it different ways, but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: Just to make sure: are we really talking about WPF application? If so, please post your XAML. Also, when you say "class.cs", do you mean class.xaml.cs?

Comment: No, i mean the: Right Click Your Project->Add->New Item->Class1.cs

Comment: Well, in that case your class is simply not aware of the radio button presence. Are you trying the MVVM approach? I.e. is class.cs acting as a view-model?

Comment: Sorry, are you try change Name to x:Name at XAML?

Comment: @progpow It won't help as he isn't even working with codebehind.

Comment: Did you try to make this radiobutton as public?

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka - How do i do that i WPF?

Comment: @Somedust it`s not working at code because he wrong define it at xaml.

Comment: @user2944342 Can you show your xaml?

Comment: @progpow No, it isn't. If you don't know the difference between Name and x:Name, you can always Google it. First search result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you are trying to access the value of your radioButton in your class.cs, right? If so, you can make a public property, which encapsulates your radiobutton-checked-property.

This can look like:

```
public bool IsRadioButtonChecked
{
   get{return radioButton1.IsChecked;}
}
```

In your class.cs you need an instance of the window.

Comment: WPF RadioButton doesn't seem to expose Checked property, only the IsChecked one.

Comment: Sorry. Mixed up WinForms and WPF

Answer (score 0):

The radio button that you created on your form is stored in a private variable in the MainForm class. Therefore, it is inaccessible from other classes.

You could turn it into a public variable, but this is not a very good approach, and in any case, will be overwritten by the Forms designer as you add/remove/resize controls on the form.

The better solution would be to pass the reference to the radio button to your other class, either via the constructor, or as an argument to the method that is checking the status of the radio button (if it is invoked by the form).

For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private mRbutton;

    public MyClass(RadioButton rbutton) {
        mRbutton = rbutton;
        // Rest of the construction code...
    }

    //
    // ... Rest of the class code ...
    //

    public void MessageShowingMethod() {
        if (mRbutton.IsChecked == true) {
            MessageBox.Show("Cancelled sending !");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If he was doing a windows form project this would be correct. Mind you, sure it will work in wpf just as well, but its not really in line with the whole mvvm thing, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe. In your main form:

```
if (radioButton1.IsChecked == true)
{
  int checked = 1;
}

callMyMethod(checked);
```

And then in your class.cs:

```
public callMyMethod(int checked)
{
  if (checked == 1)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Cancelled sending !");
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Something else");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using WPF, we have `Window` and `UserControl` classes, among other things. These are partial classes, which means that they have more than one file in them. There is a `.xaml` file where we define the UI and a code behind `.xaml.cs` file where we can access the *named* UI elements that we defined in the related `.xaml` file. *You should never access a UI element in any other class*.

To access a UI element in the code behind file, you must first name it in the `.xaml` file:

```
<RadioButton Name="RadioButton" />
```

Then, *in the code behind file only*, you can access it using that name:

```
if (RadioButton.IsChecked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cancelled sending !");
}
```

Once again, *you should never access a UI element in any other class*.