# WPF textblock does not update

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF project in that I have multiple WPF windows.

In one of the window, I called it Window2 I have a text block as follow:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Name="motorTitle" Text="this is test" Visibility="Visible" Foreground="Red" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
```

In the code behind of Window2 file, I have the following:

```
public string text = ".";    
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.motorTitle.Text = text;
}
```

In a different WPF window I called it MainWindow I try to update the text of Window2 by doing this

```
   Window2.text = "my text";
```

So, when I run in debug mode, I can see Window2's text variable changed to "my text" but it does not update to the textblock on the display.?

I did a try & catch but nothing found.

Any idea?

Comment: Show the code that creates and starts your timer. Also, have you set a breakpoint in the timer_Tick to verify it is being called?

Comment: code that start timer is this
        public DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();

and yes, the breakpoint shows data in "text".

Comment: You have to debug your code: is timer event occurs at all? Then tell what is `Window2`: is it an instance? Are you sure it's same instance (newbies often create `new` instance instead of using correct shown window one)? Also, I'd use `x:Name` instead of `Name`, don't ask me [why](http://stackoverflow.com/q/589874/1997232).

Comment: the timer event works. Windows2 is an instance created in MainWindow

Comment: I see this error when I try to write motorTitle.text = text;

"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Comment: @user1801381 Use `Dispatcher.Invoke` to solve the cross-thread problem. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use binding for the Textblock's text property and implement INotifyPropertyChanged, like this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx