# Create a component and reuse it in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1, components

I want to create some components and reuse them in different pages, put more than one in a page, etc.

For example, I want to create a component that contains an image, some text, etc. The position of the elements are fixed, but I will change the image, the text... I mean, in a same page I want to put three circles with different image and text...

What is the best way to do it? I've found UserControl, but I'm unable to call a method from another page to change something.

This is my component XAML

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="aa.Components.CircularGraph"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Components"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid Name="view">
        <Image Name="imageGraph" Source="../Assets/aa/circuloGris.png" 
       />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Name="firstLine" Text="1" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="9"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="secondLine" Text="2" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="9"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="thirdLine" Text="3" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="9"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Its code:

```
 public sealed partial class CircularGraph: UserControl {
        public CircularGraph() {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            Height = 300;
            Width = 400;
        }

        public void changeFirstLine(string var) {
            firstLine.Text = var;
        }
    }
```

In other page I put:

```
<local:CircularGraph Name="circularGraph"/>
```

And I've tried to put this in .cs:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {            
             circularGraph.changeFirstLine("aaa");
}
```

But I have an error: The name 'circularGraph' does not exits in the current context.

How can I do this?

Sorry if it's a simple question. I'm newbie at Windows phone.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `x:Name` instead of `Name`. "All `x:Name` means to XAML is generate a field to store the value in the code behind class."

```
<local:CircularGraph x:Name="circularGraph"/>
```

[In WPF, what are the differences between the x:Name and Name attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes)