# Why user control which was set in xaml is not recognized in cs?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a simple User Control and used it in the xaml file (`mainWindow.xaml`).

I named the instance `VolumeMeter` of the user control and then tried to use it in function in the cs file (`mainWindow.cs`) but the name is not recognized

> The name doesn't exist in the current context

Why is that and what can I do to fix it?

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="testUserControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:MyNameSpace="clr-namespace:testUserControl.UserControls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Name="btnShow" Content="Show"></Button>
        <StackPanel Name="stkTest" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
            <MyNameSpace:UserControl1 Name="VolumeMeter"></MyNameSpace:UserControl1>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

cs file:

```
namespace testUserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnShow_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             VolumeMeter.Enable = false;//Compile error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your are trying to access Enable property of the usercontrol. Is it a custom property. UserControl will only have IsEnabled property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `x:Name` instead of `Name`  [[msdn]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx):

```
...
<StackPanel Name="stkTest" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
   <MyNameSpace:UserControl1 x:Name="VolumeMeter"></MyNameSpace:UserControl1>
</StackPanel>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using x:Name would work. Please refer [In WPF, what are the differences between the x:Name and Name attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes) for a very good explanation.

Comment: That would be another error: ...does not contain a definition for 'Enable' and no extension method 'Enable' accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `x:Name` rather than `Name`
see this post to see the difference
[In WPF, what are the differences between the x:Name and Name attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes)