# WPF name of image

Tags: c#, wpf

I use WPF , and I create an like this

```
<Image Name="imageName" Grid.Row="0" Source="r.jpg" />
```

but with c# when I try to access this image and write 
imageName, sometimes I can not see anything
why?

Comment: Are you sure this image isn't in DataTemplate or ControlTemplate? And you should use `x:Name` instead of `Name`

Comment: why should i need x:Name ? when i try to edit Lable orTEXTBOX i use on "name" only. no x:Name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes/593151#593151