# How to control a xaml button from C# in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a xaml file with buttons like this

```
<Button Grid.Column="4" BorderThickness="0">3</Button>
<Button Grid.Column="5" BorderThickness="0">4</Button>
```

The Problem is I can't manage to control the buttons in C#. I've read about templates and resources and tried it but I am unsure if I did was correct.

Most examples online just have a click function but I wan't full control of the button having all of them in a 2D Array and changing them when I want to.

So How do I point to a button created in the xaml file so that I could do

```
button.Content = "test";
```

or whatever.

Comment: you want a reference to your control in xaml ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sounds like you are going to have lot of work to maintain your approach later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the answers about naming buttons in XAML are right.

```
<Button x:Name="btn0"/>
<Button x:Name="btn1"/>
```

Naming components make them public, thus you can easily access to them in the code behind. 
If you want, you can later create List of buttons and add them one by one. And then just access to the list.

Comment: What is the difference here between x:Name and Name

Comment: @danielps1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes

Comment: If Name is available as a property on the class, Name and x:Name can be used interchangeably as attributes.
But, you cannot use both at the same time on the same element. 

There is no difference.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx
Look at this link

Answer (score 2):

You should give a `Name` to your controls in the XAML like this

```
<Button Name="FirstButton" Grid.Column="4" BorderThickness="0">3</Button>
```

Then you'll be able to access it in the code-behind :

```
FirstButton.Content = "test"
```

Answer (score 1):

set in xaml

```
<Button content="test"/>
```

or in code behind

```
<Button x:Name = "MyButton"/>

MyButton.Content = "Test";
```

Answer (score 1):

You just give the button a name and that name you use in code

```
<Button x:Name="btnBla"/>

btnBla.Background = Brushes.SaddleBrown;
```