# How to use custom TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I created custom class ingeriting from `TextBox` and I use it in one of my window. Class is in root of project so it's namespace is: `Firm`

To use this class from root of project I added line into xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Firm.Prijem.PaletaWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:mynms="clr-namespace:Firm"> <--- ADDED LINE

       <mynms:SelectAllTextBox Name="textBoxMnozstvi" />
</Window>
```

But now when I try to run my code. I got error, because "`name 'textBoxMnozstvi' does not exist in current context`" on line:

```
 String text = textBoxMnozstvi.Text;
```

Why is that? Is now the `textBoxMnozstvi` in another namespace?

Comment: have you tried <mynms:SelectAllTextBox x:Name="textBoxMnozstvi" /> ??

Comment: Okey, that was easy.. thanks for help, if you can post this as answer I will marked as accepted... Will be best if you you could post even some reason why I have to use `x` now.. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
<mynms:SelectAllTextBox x:Name="textBoxMnozstvi" />
```

There are already some good explanations on Name vs x:Name [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes)

Comment: @Sk1X1 not a problem, glad to help :)