# Disable a context menu button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a button that looks like:

[image]

Here is the xaml:

```xaml
<Button x:Name="InstallButtonContainer" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StyleAppButton}" Grid.Column="3" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="InstallButton" Content="Install" Grid.Column="0"
            Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey= StyleDropDownButton}"
            ToolTip="{x:Static local:ToolTipStrings.INSTALLBUTTONTOOLTIP}" Click="InstallButton_Click"
            ToolTipService.ShowDuration="2000" 
            Margin="-20,-2,-4.5,-2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="51" FontFamily="Calibri"  />
        <Button x:Name="DropdownButton" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="18,-2,-20,-2" 
             Width="14" Click="load_install_dropdown" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey= StyleDropDownButton}">
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="ButtonContextMenu">
                    <MenuItem Header="Install" Click="BaseReleaseInstallContextMenuClick" x:Name="MultiInstallBtn">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Width="12" Height="12">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <ImageSource>Resources/install.ico</ImageSource>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Silent Install" Click="BaseReleaseSilentInstallContextMenuClick" x:Name="MultiInstallSilentBtn">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Width="12" Height="12">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <ImageSource>Resources/install.ico</ImageSource>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Download" Click="BaseReleaseMultipleDownloadContextMenuClick">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Width="12" Height="12">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <ImageSource>Resources/Down.png</ImageSource>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Path x:Name="BtnArrow" Margin="-3,-10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="8" Height="10" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" 
                    Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Now based on some condition, I want to disable the Install and Silent Install buttons through code.

I tried using:

```
if(condition)
{
    MultiInstallBtn.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

but it does not seems to work. Is there anything wrong in the way I am accessing it?

Comment: So, although they are disabled you can still click them and they execute?

Comment: Where are you trying disable menu item? I am unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you try changing `x:Name="MultiInstallBtn"` to `Name="MultiInstallBtn"`? `Name` setting would mean setting control Name and `x:Name` is mostly used to perform bindings with command in code behind (which you are certainly not doing here!).

Comment: @praty That is completely incorrect.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, a reference to my understanding from an old SO answers (para4) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes#answer-593151. I do not suggest my post to be an answer but just a hit and trial.

Comment: @praty Then you've totally misunderstood how it works.

Comment: @praty btw. it's "Hit-and-miss" or "Trial-and-error"

Comment: You could just use a style and a `Trigger` or `DataTrigger` or even an `EventTrigger` to disable the `ContextMenu`. I have noticed that you already apply a style to your button so add `BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleDropDownButton}"` to your style so you can keep using unified button.

Answer (score 0):

As long as that code is in the code behind of the control then it should work.

I notice that there may be some custom styling being applied too.  Could it be that you are missing styling for the menu item disabled state?  So the menu item is actually disabled, but visually it doesn't present in a different way?

Check that in the style or control template for the Menu Item that it is reacting to the control's IsEnabled property or that there's a "Disabled" VisualState defined.