# xaml - bind gridview columns to a checbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

I am using telerik radgridviews and I have some columns that I want to show only if a checkbox is checked.The checkbox is outside the grid and the columns I want to show/hide are inside another grid. This is what I have tried, but doesn't seem to work:

```
<Grid>
<Checkbox Name = "test">
</Grid>
<telerik:RadGridView ...>
     <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
         <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                  <telerik:RadGridView ...                                
                    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                       <telerik:GridViewDataColumn IsVisible="{Binding IsChecked,Source={x:Reference test}, Converter{StaticResource BooleanToVis}}" />                                                                                                                                
         </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    </telerik:RadGridView>
              </DataTemplate>
             </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Update #2
So I have the below, but it doesn't seem to work .I dont get any binding issues but checking or unchecking the checkbox doesnt do anything.

```
 public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return isChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isChecked != value)
            {
                isChecked = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));
            }
        }
    }

<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVis"/>         
<CheckBox x:Name="showCols" Content="test" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>                                             
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding x}" IsVisible="{Binding DataContext.IsChecked,Source={x:Reference showCols},Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVis}}" />
```

Comment: The binding on your CheckBox needs to be TwoWay: `IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: @Shawn thanks, but it is still not working, not sure if this has to do with telerik or something else..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood you correctly you are looking to change the visibility of a `GridViewDataColumn` based on a `checkbox`, there are basically two ways to do that:

- The easy and straightforward way to do this is simply by binding the column's `IsVisible` property to the `CheckBox`'s `IsChecked` porperty using `elementname`:

  ```
  <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid Grid.Row="0">
          <CheckBox Name="ChkBox" />
      </Grid>
      <telerik:RadGridView  Grid.Row="1">
          <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
              <telerik:GridViewDataColumn IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=ChkBox}"  Header="First Name" UniqueName="FirstName" />
              <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  Header="Last Name" UniqueName="LasttName" />
          </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
      </telerik:RadGridView>
  </Grid>
  ```
- The other way is to bind both the `IsChecked` dependency property of the checkbox and the `IsVisible` of the `GridViewDataColumn` to the same property:

  ```
  <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid Grid.Row="0">
          <CheckBox Name="ChkBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedP}"/>
      </Grid>
      <telerik:RadGridView  Grid.Row="1">
          <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
              <telerik:GridViewDataColumn IsVisible="{Binding IsCheckedP}"  Header="First Name" UniqueName="FirstName" />
              <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  Header="Last Name" UniqueName="LasttName" />
          </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
      </telerik:RadGridView>
  </Grid>


    private bool _isChecked;
      public bool IsCheckedP
      {
          get { return _isChecked; }
          set
          {
              _isChecked = value;
              OnPropertyChanged();
          }
      }

      public ViewModel()
      {
          //...
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;          
      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
  ```

Make sure to implement the *INotifyPropertyChanged* interface and to properly set the `DataContext`.

Answer (score 0):

try this (source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074985/5605739) )

```
<FrameworkElement x:Name="dummyElement"  Visibility="Collapsed"  />
<DataGrid .... >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsChecked, 
                                                 Source={x:Reference dummyElement}, 
                                                 Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"  />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

change your `Name="test"` for `x:Name="test"`  (difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/593151/5605739))

Comment: not familiar with FrameworkElement..do I still need to have the checkbox?

Comment: @user1855165 sure, you can use your checkbox instead of it